# DateTime loop in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

Probably friday's are bit hard to think about logic. May be this might be simple logic.

My issue  was I've a yesterday's date time. I've hourValue from 7,8,9...23, 0,1,2,3,6.

```
DateTime yesterday_datetime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);    
DateTime todays_datetime = new DateTime();
```

In the Hours loop I need to add hourvalue in below code.

```
todays_datetime = yesterday_datetime.AddHours(hourValue);
```

But When it comes to hourvalue 0 it was taking yesterday's date only not today's date.

I was adding hours from 7,8,9...23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6 to 30/05/2013 so if 7 was added to 30/05/2013 then it will be 30/05/2013 07:00:00 and so on till 23 it was 30/05/2013 23:00:00. Now coming to 0..6 it should be 31/05/2013 00:00:00 and 31/05/2013 01:00:00 and so on

Am I missing anything here? Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Could you maybe add some example output together with an information what you would have expected. THat would make it easier to find the issue here.

Comment: Not sure whether I'm getting you right, but `yesterday_datetime.AddHours(0)` is actually still `yesterday_datetime`.

Comment: disagree about first line+first sentence.

Comment: @Freelancer well I don't mind

Comment: If you want Hour 0 to be today why not just use an if statement, check for 0 and reset to 24?  Then your AddHours will push the date to today.

Comment: Not sure, what you're trying to do... maybe this `while (yesterday < today) { yesterday = yesterday.AddHours(1); }` or simply `today = yesterday.AddHours(hourValue == 0 ? 24 : hourValue);` will do what you want. Depending on what logic you want to achieve.

Comment: Unfortunately, this issue is posed without the "why" component.  That's why you're getting answers that are all over the place.  Define the "what I have" and the "what I want from it" and you'll get to the point faster.

Comment: Can you show your loop ? your question seems vague

Comment: @MatthiasMeid yes but I'm adding from 7...23, 0 right so when you add 23 to yesterday date and then adding 0 should be todays' date right..Imagine hours are in loop from 7....23, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: @user1990395 No, when you add 23 hours to yesterday, you almost certainly HAVE today.

Comment: No! you're adding *zero* hours to yesterday. Of course it'll still be yesterday!

Comment: @corak I know but when you add 23 then adding 0 should be todays date right? Imagine hourvalue from (7,8,9...23, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6) and loop will start from 7 and end with 6

Comment: Except when you're doing it between midnight and 1 am. Meaning, you'll probably get todays *date*, but you will always be one hour ago.

Comment: @Corak I was adding hours from 7,8,9...23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6 to 30/05/2013 so if 7 was added to 30/05/2013 then it will be 30/05/2013 07:00:00 and so on till 23 it was 30/05/2013 23:00:00. Now coming to 0..6 it should be 31/05/2013 00:00:00 and 31/05/2013 01:00:00

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed the `.Date`. Yeah, so no. `DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1).AddHours(0);` will *always* be yesterday at midnight. Like I said, I don't know what you want to do, but working with an `hourValue` just seems wrong. Maybe you want to take a step back, and look at what you're doing. You're adding *zero* hours (i.e. *nothing*) to yesterday midnight and expect it to be today midnight.

Answer (score 2):

If you did somthing like

```
var now = DateTime.Now
for (var time = now.AddDays(-1); time < now; time = time.AddHours(1))
{
    // time enumerates the hours between yesterday and now.
}
```

it should work fine.

---

or, if you dont like loops,

```
var yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
var hourTimes = Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
    .Select(hourValue => yesterday.Add(hourValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

I might not fully comprehend the problem: If you have hourValue 0 and add those to yesterday's datetime, that value will not change. Right?

Comment: right, judging from the question, this is the right answer. I'm just assuming the questions is mispresented.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want this, but you could try something like:

```
while (yesterday_datetime <= todays_datetime)
{
    // some logic

    yesterday_datetime = yesterday_datetime.AddHours(hourValue);
}
```

You will loop in the dateTime until the `yesterday_datetime` get the same datetime of `todays_datetime`, hour by `hourValue`. You have to assegure the `hourValue` is not 0.

Comment: Let me try and will come back

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your hour values:

**Your values now:**

7,8,9...23, **0,1,2,3,6.**

**Your values ought to be:**

7,8,9...23, **24, 25, ...**

Else if you call 'AddHours(0)', it's still the yesterday's date:

```
Console.WriteLine(
(yesterday_datetime.AddHours(0) == yesterday_datetime).ToString()
);
```

prints 'True'

Answer (score 0):

```
todays_datetime = yesterday_datetime.AddHours(hourValue);
```

In your code you didn't updated the yesterday_datetime object. It still pointed to the previous day even after you added some hours to it. You have to update yesterday_datetime assign yesterday_datetime to todays_datetime  for first and use today_datetime for further process.

```
DateTime yesterday_datetime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);    
DateTime todays_datetime = yesterday_datetime ;
todays_datetime = todays_datetime .AddHours(hourValue);
```

Comment: Then todat_datetime will add hours like 7+8 = 15 then 15+9 = 24 and son

Comment: AddDays method will set the time value to zero (hours, minutes, seconds). The result will contain only date information.

Answer (score 0):

If possible in your case you could simple use:
hourValue: 7,8,9...23,24,25,26,27,28.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm starting to understand.  Try this:

```
for (Int32 i = -24; i <= 23; i++)
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.AddHours(i).Day, DateTime.Now.AddHours(i).Hour, DateTime.Now.AddHours(i).Minute, DateTime.Now.AddHours(i).Second);
    Console.writeLine(dt.ToString());
}
```

Right now, in USA EST I get:

```
5/30/2013 7:52:06 AM
5/30/2013 8:52:06 AM
5/30/2013 9:52:06 AM
5/30/2013 10:52:06 AM
5/30/2013 11:52:06 AM
5/30/2013 12:52:06 PM
5/30/2013 1:52:06 PM
5/30/2013 2:52:06 PM
5/30/2013 3:52:06 PM
5/30/2013 4:52:06 PM
5/30/2013 5:52:06 PM
5/30/2013 6:52:06 PM
5/30/2013 7:52:06 PM
5/30/2013 8:52:06 PM
5/30/2013 9:52:06 PM
5/30/2013 10:52:06 PM
5/30/2013 11:52:06 PM
5/30/2013 12:52:06 AM
5/30/2013 1:52:06 AM
5/30/2013 2:52:06 AM
5/30/2013 3:52:06 AM
5/30/2013 4:52:06 AM
5/30/2013 5:52:06 AM
5/30/2013 6:52:06 AM
5/31/2013 7:52:06 AM
5/31/2013 8:52:06 AM
5/31/2013 9:52:06 AM
5/31/2013 10:52:06 AM
5/31/2013 11:52:06 AM
5/31/2013 12:52:06 PM
5/31/2013 1:52:06 PM
5/31/2013 2:52:06 PM
5/31/2013 3:52:06 PM
5/31/2013 4:52:06 PM
5/31/2013 5:52:06 PM
5/31/2013 6:52:06 PM
5/31/2013 7:52:06 PM
5/31/2013 8:52:06 PM
5/31/2013 9:52:06 PM
5/31/2013 10:52:06 PM
5/31/2013 11:52:06 PM
5/31/2013 12:52:06 AM
5/31/2013 1:52:06 AM
5/31/2013 2:52:06 AM
5/31/2013 3:52:06 AM
5/31/2013 4:52:06 AM
5/31/2013 5:52:06 AM
5/31/2013 6:52:06 AM
```